# When writing VBA I cannot get two specific errors to run through

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an Invalid use of code on my first line, and I am getting a Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed when inputting my object as the range.  Can anyone assist?

```
Sub SplitandFilterSheet()

    Dim SplitOrderNum As Range

    Sheets("Sum To Line Item").Select

    Set SplitOrderNum = Range("SplitOrderNum")

    For Each cell In SplitOrderNum
        Sheets("Sum To Line Item").Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value

        With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cell.Value).Range("OrderData")
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>" & cell.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With

        ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, read the comments inside and look for the <<<< Customize this >>> lines:

```
Sub SplitandFilterSheet()

    ' Declare objects
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim splitOrderNum As Range
    Dim sourceCell As Range

    ' Declare other variables
    Dim sourceSheetName As String
    Dim sourceRangeName As String
    Dim targetSheetName As String
    Dim targetRangeName As String

    Dim lastSheetHidden As Boolean


    ' <<< Customize this >>>
    sourceSheetName = "Sum To Line Item"
    sourceRangeName = "SplitOrderNum"
    targetRangeName = "OrderData"

    ' Initialize the source sheet
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sourceSheetName)

    ' Initialize the range (Add full qualifier to the current workbook, sheet and range)
    Set splitOrderNum = sourceSheet.Range(sourceRangeName)

    ' Get if last sheet is visible in current workbook
    lastSheetHidden = Not ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Visible
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Visible = True

    For Each sourceCell In splitOrderNum
        ' Copy the source worksheet
        sourceSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        ' Rename the new worksheet
        Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Name = sourceCell.Value
        ' Reference to the added worksheet
        Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

        With targetSheet.Range(targetRangeName)
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>" & sourceCell.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With

        ' Check this next line if this should point to the orderdata range too (?)
        targetSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    Next sourceCell

    ' Return the last sheet visible state
    If lastSheetHidden = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Visible = Not lastSheetHidden
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ricardo, This is working better than the formula I had before.  However, I am running into the macro creating new tabs based on the column headers in my Sum to Line Item tab.  Could you point me in the right direction in the code as to where I incorrectly listed my target range for sheet creation?

Thank you

Comment: Hi Connor. If the named range "SplitOrderNum" includes the headers and you don't want the headers to be created as worksheets, you need to modify it by clicking in the ribbon "Formulas" | "Name Manager" | and edit the range where it "Refers to".

If this isn't what you intent to do, please edit your question and describe the steps you want the macro/code to follow.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, thank you for the help.  I now have the above code. The VBA is now creating the separate sheets. However (in this example there is three sheets being created), after the first sheet is created and the VBA runs back through the code, it copies the first sheet that was created that already has the data needed for the second and third tab pulled out so there is no data in the final two tabs.  Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: Sorry I posted my change in your code, however it deviated too far off of my original question.  The new code is posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55053905/vba-code-not-using-accurate-master-sheet-when-looping-back-second-third-time