# VBA code not using accurate master sheet when looping back second, third time

Tags: excel, vba

The VBA I created is creating the separate sheets. However (in this example there is three sheets being created), after the first sheet is created and the VBA runs back through the code, it copies the first sheet that was created, rather than the master sheet, which already has the data needed for the second and third tab filtered out so there is no data in the final two tabs. Do you know what could be causing this?  Code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub InvoiceSeperator()

    ' Declare objects
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim SplitOrderNum As Range
    Dim OrderData As Range
    Dim sourceCell As Range
    Dim allOrders As Range
    Dim invoicenumbers As Range

    ' Declare other variables
    Dim sourceSheetName As String
    Dim sourceRangeName As String
    Dim targetSheetName As String
    Dim targetRangeName As String

    Dim lastSheetHidden As Boolean

    ' <<< Customize this >>>
    sourceSheetName = "Invoices"
    targetSheetName = "SumToLineItem"
    sourceRangeName = "SplitOrderNum"
    targetRangeName = "OrderData"

    ' Initialize the source sheet
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SumToLineItem")

    Set allOrders = targetSheet.Range("B:B")
    allOrders.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets(2).Select
    Sheets(2).Name = "Invoices"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoices")
    sourceSheet.Range("A2").Select
    sourceSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="SplitOrderNum", RefersToR1C1:= _
        "=Invoices!R2C1:R4C1"

    ' Initialize the range (Add full qualifier to the current workbook, sheet and range)
    Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("SplitOrderNum")
    ' Get if last sheet is visible in current workbook
    lastSheetHidden = Not ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Visible
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Visible = True

    For Each sourceCell In sourceRange
        ' Copy the source worksheet
        targetSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        ' Rename the new worksheet
        Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Name = sourceCell.Value
        ' Reference to the added worksheet
        Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

        With targetSheet.Range(targetRangeName)
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>" & sourceCell.Value,.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With

        ' Check this next line if this should point to the orderdata range too (?)
        targetSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    Next sourceCell

    ' Return the last sheet visible state
    If lastSheetHidden = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Visible = Not lastSheetHidden
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Code looks incomplete

Comment: Updated, not sure why that happened.

Comment: You're mixing the sourceSheet and targetSheet concepts. Please explain in steps what you want to achieve with "Invoices" and the ranges you defined.